# Determine type of generic object in Java

Tags: java, json, types, instanceof

I'm processing some JSON data, and I don't know what I will receive. For example, for key "TestKey" I might get a value of "MyValue" just as likely as I will get a value of 12345 or 10/10/2005.

Is there an easy way in Java to determine the type of something generically classed as "Object"?

I just want to be able to split it up into groups like int, double, date, string, etc. And I'm sure there is a classier way to do it than look at it with regular expressions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a JSON library?

Comment: No. It's not really a JSON question to be honest... I just want to know how given an object I can interrogate it to determine which type it is.

Comment: Well they're all of type `String` until they get parsed, typically by a vetted JSON library.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can use `instanceof`, if you know the possible target object types; however, what you're trying to do may not be achievable.

Comment: All objects in Java implicitly extend the `Object` class. When dealing with JSON, the data you receive will be in the form of strings. It is up to you as the programmer to determine which data types are expected to be associated with which keys. If ambiguity is really necessary (i.e. a value may be a string, int, or another format) I'd recommend using a regexp or something like the following: `Integer.class.isInstance(yourValue)`.

Comment: Regardless if it's JSON or any other data representation, you should know if a field is of type `Date` or `int` etc. If the same field may contain either- it's designed badly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, your best choice is pass an extra field with some kind of data to identify the field type. But that would be dirty. The best option is always be sure of what kind of field will you get in the JSON, if you achieve that, then you will get compatibility with the JSON libraries like Gson. If you don't, you are by your own and you will have to pass some kind of field like `type:0` (where 0 is for int, 1 for double and so on...) and make a dirty `switch` to cast the field properly.